# GitHub Action Secrets environment can't be retrieved

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

I have a problem with a workflow GitHub Action. Secrets environment is the hardest and the most puzzling thing that GitHub invented. I'm using the following code and I realized that I can't retrieve my environment secrets as environment variable.

```
deploy-snowflake-changes-dev:
    name: deploy schemas changes to dev
    needs: ShitTest 
    if: needs.ShitTest.outputs.output == 'true'
    environment:
      name: ${{inputs.devEnv}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
          SF_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.SF_ACCOUNT }}
          SF_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.SF_USERNAME }}
          SF_ROLE: ${{ secrets.SF_ROLE }}
          SF_WAREHOUSE: ${{ secrets.SF_WAREHOUSE }}
          SF_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.SF_DATABASE }}
          SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SF_PASSWORD }}
          SF_SCHEMA: ${{secrets.SF_SCHEMA}}
          SF_HISTORY_TABLE: ${{secrets.SF_HISTORY_TABLE}}
```

When I'm trying to use the previous environnment variables in the code that follow, its doesn't work and it's like the secrets doesn't exist but they are. All these secrets are stored as the `${{inputs.devEnv}}` environnment secrets.

My question is : what happen ? How to make it work ? I'm out of solutions.

That the complete code and I have an other workflow from where I call tje below workflow with its parameters.

---

Here is the whole workflow implementation:

```
name: snowflake Devops
 
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      Organization:
        required: true
        type: string
      Repository:
        required: true
        type: string
      devEnv:
        required: true
        type: string
      uatEnv: 
        required: true
        type: string
      prodEnv:
        required: true
        type: string
      devBranch:
        required: true
        type: string
      uatBranch:
        required: true
        type: string
      prodBranch:
        required: true
        type: string
      rootFolder:
        required: true
        type: string

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  ShitTest:
    name: This is a shit test to get around the if condition
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output: ${{ steps.condition.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - name: shit test
        id: condition
        shell: pwsh
        run: |  
          $branch = '${{ github.ref }}' 
          $event = '${{ github.event_name }}'
          if($branch -eq 'refs/heads/${{ inputs.uatBranch }}' -AND $event -eq 'push' ) {
            $isTrigger = $true
            echo "::set-output name=test::$isTrigger"
            Write-Host "Deployment will be triggered" -ForegroundColor Cyan
          }else {
            $isTrigger = $false
            echo "::set-output name=test::$isTrigger"
            Write-Host "Deployment will not be triggered" -ForegroundColor Cyan
          }

  deploy-snowflake-changes-dev:
    name: deploy schamas changes to dev
    needs: ShitTest 
    if: needs.ShitTest.outputs.output == 'true'
    environment:
      name: ${{inputs.devEnv}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
          SF_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.SF_ACCOUNT }}
          SF_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.SF_USERNAME }}
          SF_ROLE: ${{ secrets.SF_ROLE }}
          SF_WAREHOUSE: ${{ secrets.SF_WAREHOUSE }}
          SF_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.SF_DATABASE }}
          SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SF_PASSWORD }}
          SF_SCHEMA: ${{secrets.SF_SCHEMA}}
          SF_HISTORY_TABLE: ${{secrets.SF_HISTORY_TABLE}}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Python 3.8.x
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.1
        with:
          python-version: 3.8.x

      - name: Run schemachange
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          echo "SF_ACCOUT"
          echo "${{env.SF_ACCOUNT}}"
          echo "GITHUB_WORKSPACE: $GITHUB_WORKSPACE"
          python --version
          echo "Step 1: Installing schemachange"
          pip install schemachange
          
          echo "Step 2: Getting variables"
          $schemachangeconfigPath = "./configurations/${{inputs.devBranch}}/schemachange-config.json"
          $variables = Get-Content $schemachangeconfigPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
          
          ## Need something like that in input of schemachange cmdline deploy : '{\"database\":\"DB_DEMO_PPROD\", \"schema\":\"DEMO\", \"table\":\"DEMO_TABLE\"}'
          $count=0
          $varsString = "{"
          foreach ($p in $variables.psobject.Properties) {
            $count+=1
            $name = $p.name 
            $value = $p.value
            if($count -ne $variables.psobject.Properties.name.Length) {
              $varsString = [System.String]::Concat($varsString,"\","`"$name","\","`"",":","\","`"$value","\","`"",",")
            }else {
              $varsString = [System.String]::Concat($varsString,"\","`"$name","\","`"",":","\","`"$value","\","`"","}")
            }
          }

          echo "Step 3: Running schemachange"
          schemachange deploy -f ./${{inputs.rootFolder}} -a ${{env.SF_ACCOUNT}} -u ${{env.SF_USERNAME}} -r ${{env.SF_ROLE}} -w ${{env.SF_WAREHOUSE}} -d ${{env.SF_DATABASE}} -c ${{env.SF_DATABASE}}.${{env.SF_SCHEMA}}.${{env.SF_HISTORY_TABLE}} --vars $varsString --create-change-history-table -v
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: When you try printing the secrets in the job steps, do they appear as `***` or empty? something like `run: echo ${{ secrets.SF_ACCOUNT }}` and `run: echo ${{ env.SF_ACCOUNT }}`

Comment: Hello GuidFalourd. The problem is precisely that I have an empty print. That's mean that hte secret is not retreived at all.

Comment: Ok. Could you share the whole workflow implementation in your question? Because I tested something similar here and everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: To give more precision I use this code in a workflow call. Is it possible that environnments doesn't work in workflows call ?

Comment: The problem is actually with secrets in that case. Secrets can't be used directly in a reusable workflow (using workflow_call) without being inherited from the main workflow. Check the [official doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow) for more details. In that case, you probably will have to use the environment configuration on the main workflow :)

Comment: The problem was solved for SF_ACCOUNT by using the syntax secrets: inherit in the main workflow but I still have the same problem for the others secrets. It's incomprehensible :/

Comment: How did you configure the `secrets` in the `workflow_call` trigger?

Comment: I added the `secrets: inherit` parameter under the `uses:` parameter. after that I tryed all the solution proposed in the following website but all trigger a syntax error in GitHub. https://colinsalmcorner.com/consuming-environment-secrets-in-reusable-workflows/

Comment: I can read in this post that this error is known : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534117/github-actions-referencing-environment-secrets-in-reusable-workflows

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using the same example as suggested [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1490#issuecomment-970642607) as well for now, as there is no native solution yet.

Comment: Yes, I think it will work but it obligates us to have secrets with the environment prefix and it's a shame. I will try it right now.

Comment: Please, add an answer with your solution later, it might be helpful to others :)

Comment: I tend to think it's hopeless on GitHub. I don't have anything working at the moment. I'll post a solution if I find one by tomorrow. If not I will drop GitHub. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about the answer that I gave below ? :)

Comment: The answer is great! However shouldn't ask another question there, but start a new question thread with the details to reproduce the issue calling the GitHub REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to make it work. It was necessary to add a `secrets` section in both the caller workflow and the called workflow as the following :

- sample of the called workflow

```
secrets:
      TOKEN:
        required: true
      SF_DATABASE:
        required: true
      SF_SCHEMA:
        required: true
      SF_HISTORY_TABLE:
        required: true
```

- sample of the caller workflow :

```
secrets:
      TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      SF_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.SF_DATABASE }}
      SF_SCHEMA: ${{secrets.SF_SCHEMA}}
      SF_HISTORY_TABLE: ${{secrets.SF_HISTORY_TABLE}}
```

And then, secrets in the called workflow can be used as the following : `${{ secrets.SF_DATABASE }}`

Comment: Wow I spend hours on this. Great tip. What a confusing feature https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#using-secrets-in-a-workflow